# Override window.print() for all windows using window prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

While playing around with Javascript, I tried modifying object prototypes.

For `String.toString()`, this worked:

```
var testString = "Test";
testString.toString(); // returns "Test"
String.prototype.toString=function(){return "modified :-)";}
testString.toString(); // now returns "modified :-)"
```

However, this does not work:

```
Window.prototype.print=function(){
    console.log("disabled");
}
window.print(); // still opens the print dialog
```

Why is this not working?
Is `window.print()` somehow special? Or is it `Window` that is special?

**Note:**

This only seems to occur in Firefox (tested on V40). In Chrome and Internet Explorer, `window.print()` is disabled as expected.

Is that a Firefox bug, or by design?

Comment: Seems to be working for me? http://jsfiddle.net/a869ecee/

Comment: Strange... works for me,too, in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. Question edited.

Comment: Overriding the `toString` method on `Window.prototype` seem only work in Firefox [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hwo71j8/). `Window` might have some none overridable behaviour. BTW can always do `window.print=function(){...}`

Comment: On firefox console (ctrl+shift+K), it gives error: `"TypeError: Window.prototype is undefined"`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any official documentation, but it seems that the `window.print()` method is protected inside of FF.

However, if you're happy not to use `prototype`, the following works fine in Chrome and FF (not tested in IE,though):

```
window.print = function()
{
    console.log('disabled');
}

window.print();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a869ecee/2/)

Comment: Yes, I know I can override `window.print` directly. I was curious specifically why it does not work via the prototype. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Howver, this will **not** override the behavior of the print command or ctrl-p.